# Should class attribute be tree-like or flat?

Tags: python

I have a class `student` with attribute `name` like this:

```
class student(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Now if I want some sub-attributes, like first name, middle name and last name, should I use a tree-like structure:

```
class student(object):
    ...
        self.name.first = first_name
        self.name.middle = middle_name
        self.name.last = last_name
```

or change the attribute flatly to 3 attributes

```
class student(object):
    ...
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.middle_name = middle_name
        self.last_name = last_name
```

Comment: If `name` is not an object with some meaningful methods (for example nice `__repr__`) then use the second approach.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do and how you want to do it

Comment: I agree with @timgeb, an example of a place you would use the first method is say you have a `Person` class and you have a `Head` class, then it would be meaningful to have something like `Head.eyeColor`, and `Head.hairColor`. In your specific example it doesn't seem necessary.

Comment: @timgeb In this example it's trivial but in my real code it is meaningful, problem is I've not seen tree-like attributes anywhere? Usually it's `self.name` + a method, rather than sub-attribute starts with dot.

Comment: @ElyFialkoff I think that is a good answer to this question if you also include an example when you shouldn't do tree like

Comment: I would say that for this particular example it doesn't provide more clarity or code reuse so there is no reason to have it tiered like the first method. Its not a clear answer, but I would say that if the 2 aspects can be separate and used in different places. Maybe you have a `Student` class and you have a `Teacher` class, it is then possible that you can create a `Name` class, however this can be avoided by simply have a `Person` class and then simply inheriting from that class, that class can follow the second method given.

Comment: @ElyFialkoff If creating a `Name` class then the example problem is solved, but what if there is a more complex case, say I have a `Person` class, `Head` class, then `eye` class, `comea` class... so all defined as classes until the very last level, I can have `comea.color`?

Comment: It is almost impossible to answer this question since it depends on the specifics. Here is a general rule. Will you use the subclass again somewhere else in the future? Does another class need to use the subclass as well? Can you design it differently with inheritance? What is more clear/readable/understandable for your needs? Are you overthinking this/ are you making this more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: @ElyFialkoff Thanks for the questions, I was overthinking and I need to think a bit more and get my hands dirty now.

Comment: You just said you were over thinking, its time to just get your hands dirty without thinking too much. It is easy to get distracted from the task by the details. You should try and get it running first (at least at the beginning) and then worry about design and re-usability a little later. when you get more experience you will start making these decisions as you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP 20 -- The Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) advises that flat is better than nested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
from collections import namedtuple
class student(object):
    name_type = namedtuple('name', ['first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name'])
    def __init__(self, name: name_type):
        self.name = name
```

so that:

```
s = student(student.name_type('John', 'Jack', 'Smith'))
print(s.name.first_name, s.name.middle_name, s.name.last_name)
```

outputs:

```
John Jack Smith
```

Comment: The questions is if you should ;)

Comment: True that. It's really a matter of opinion IMHO. Voting to close then.